# stringbuiler save to CSV file out of memory

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, stringbuilder

I need to save a large data table (**5000** rows and **8880** columns) to CSV file. So I  save the `DataTable` to `StringBuilder` first and use `File.WriteAllText` to save to file. But because of the *size* of the table, it gives me *out of memory exception*. I am thinking using `StreamWriter`. Could anyone help how to use `StreamWriter` instead?

Thanks!

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        string[] CSVcolumnNames = sortedDT.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                          Select(column => column.ColumnName).
                                          ToArray();
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", CSVcolumnNames));

        foreach (DataRow row in sortedDT.Rows)
        {
            string[] fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).
                                            ToArray();
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
        }

        File.WriteAllText(CSVpath, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Short answer: Ctrl-H `StreamBuilder` -> `StreamWriter`. Ctrl-H `Append`-> `Write`. Fix filename, remove last line. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this is tested and works fine:

```
       using System.IO;

        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(CSVpath))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(string.Join(",", sortedDT.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => column.ColumnName)));

            foreach (DataRow row in sortedDT.Rows)
            {
               sw.WriteLine(string.Join(",", row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString())));

            }
        }
```

This code write `fields` line to file which name `CSVpath`. First columns name and then values

Comment: Isnt calling ToArray unnecessary? string.Join works with IEnumerable. To add efficiency - maybe avoiding string.join is as well good idea

Comment: Thanks a lot for the posting. I saw that you change string[] to var, any purpose for that?

Comment: @Daniel It is only refactoring. `string.Join` accept `IEnumerable` interface so is no need to use `ToArray()` method.  For Your problem with performace is good to avoid unnessesery work.  I tested this and it works perfect as You want

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will test and let you know

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `File.WriteAllText()` which wants *all* the data in the *memory*, use `File.WriteAllLines()` instead (it requires memory for *one line* only):

```
var source = sortedDT.Rows
  .OfType<DataRow>() 
  .Select(row => String.Join(",", row.ItemArray));

File.WriteAllLines(CSVpath, source);
```

As you see `File.WriteAllLines` does everything for you and you don't have to use `StreamWriter`. In case you want add titles (Columns' Names):

```
var columnNames = String.Join(",", sortedDT.Columns
  .OfType<DataColumn>()
  .Select(column => column.ColumnName));

var data = sortedDT.Rows
  .OfType<DataRow>() 
  .Select(row => String.Join(",", row.ItemArray));

var source = new String[] {columnNames}
  .Concat(data);

File.WriteAllLines(CSVpath, source);
```

Comment: @Daniel: the only memory problem can be from `sortedDT` , the solution's request is a memory for one line/row only.